# How to do something depending the condition in Nightmare?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I'm creating a script using `Nightmare`, steps of my scripts necessaries are:

1. Open the page
2. Check is logged with cookie
3. Login is not logged
4. Do all the rest task

Something like this code:

```
nightmare
    .goto(url)
    .cookies.get('cookie_key')
    .then(cookie => {

    })
    ;
```

How to can I make to nightmare login if is not logged, before execute rest of necessary tasks?

Comment: Can't you just put an `if` statement in your `then()`?

Answer (score 1):

@4castle is right: You should be able to put your `if` block directly in your `.then()`.  For example:

```
nightmare
  .goto(url)
  .cookies.get('cookie_key')
  .then(cookie => {
    if(cookie){
      //perform your login action
      return nightmare
        .type('#username', username)
        .type('#password', password)
    } else {
      //if you need to perform other logic 
      //if you're already logged in, do it here
      //otherwise, this `else` can be omitted
    }
  })
  .then(()=>{
    return nightmare
      .action()
      .action()
      //etc.
  })
```

For further reading, you might want to have a look at [Running Multiple Steps](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-examples/blob/master/docs/beginner/promises.md#running-multiple-steps) in [`nightmare-examples`](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-examples).